# Resize controls in a form by keeping their aspect ratio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, resize, aspect-ratio

I have a very basic login form with the login centred (pictured). I would like the 5 controls to resize so that they remain within the blue box of the background (like in figure 1).

I have tried to use the `anchor` property (all 4 sides) but the results were very bad.

Also, I am not sure, but I don't think that the text of the text link and checkbox text resizes? Is there any way to do this? I know that the `Font` property is read only, so I can't adjust it like that.

Login at regular size
[image: Login at regular size]

Full screen login. Grows too big. Distorts.
[image: Full screen login]

As small as the login will get before the controls disappear.
[image: Small login]

Comment: Please do not Re-tag it with VBA Tag. This has nothing to do with VBA. Perhaps you want VB.Net?

Comment: @siddharth-rout Sorry. VB.Net is what I meant.

Comment: You are asking various things, but the answer to all of them is the same one: take care of every situation independently. For example: with a button of 50*50, store the ratio (1), resize one of the dimensions (e.g., width) & apply the ratio to get the other dimension; all this from a place where you get updated information about the form size (e.g., its `SizeChanged` event). `Font` is readonly but you can assign a new instance. For example: `control.Font = new Font(whatever)`. I hope that anything of this will help you, but I am afraid that this question is too broad for SO.